# React Native Singleton in Navigation stack

Tags: react-native, navigation, singleton

The React-Native `Navigator` component maintains a "stack" of components, which constitute it's navigation history. If some of those components bind to native modules, for instance the `react-native-camera` library, of which expect to be considered a singleton (that is, exist at most once at a time), what would be the best way to manage that requirement? My first stab would be to only allow `pop()` from that singleton component, but I would like something less restrictive.